# powershell script for ldif file

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

How to write a powershell script to extract records not having goEmpid and output into a file For ldif file containing this

```
"dn: cn=username,ou=organisationname,ou=org-ca,ou=go-pki,o=finance of organisation,st=on,c=ca,
cn:username mail:username@org.ca
uid: username
goEmpid:2273773

dn: cn=username1,ou=organisationname,ou=org-ca,ou=go-pki,o=finance of organisation,st=on,c=ca,
cn:username1 mail:username1@org.ca
uid: username1

dn: cn=username2,ou=organisationname,ou=org-ca,ou=go-pki,o=finance of organisation,st=on,c=ca,
cn:username2 mail:username2@org.ca
uid: username2

dn: cn=username3,ou=organisationname,ou=org-ca,ou=go-pki,o=finance of organisation,st=on,c=ca,
cn:username3 mail:username3@org.ca
uid: username3
goEmpid:2273776"
```

```
# the path to LDIF file
$ldifFilePath = "C:\Users\91701\Desktop\pki.ldif"

# the path for the output file
$outputFilePath = "C:\Users\91701\Desktop\output.txt"

# Reading the content of the LDIF file
$ldifContent = Get-Content $ldifFilePath -Raw

# Split LDIF content into individual records
$ldifRecords = $ldifContent -split "^\s*$" | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }

# Initializing an empty array to store records with missing 'goEmpid'
$missingGoEmpidRecords = @()

# Loop through each record and check if 'goEmpid' is missing
foreach ($record in $ldifRecords) {
    if ($record -notmatch 'goEmpid') {
        $missingGoEmpidRecords += @"
        Record with missing 'goEmpid':
     $record
    -------------------------
     "@
}
```

}

```
# Output the missing 'goEmpid' records to the console
Write-Output $missingGoEmpidRecords

# Save the output to a file
$missingGoEmpidRecords | Out-File -FilePath $outputFilePath -Append
```

Q This gives me an empty file without displaying records missing goEmpid`'

Comment: Welcome to SO. I am unsure what your question is actually about? Your data look like the CSV representation of AD account data but you seem to try to treat them like plain text. You may explain a little more detailed what you're trying to do. There might be a better way. And BTW: You should format your code properly using a [code block]. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so first I'm assuming LDIF is [LDAP Data Interchange Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAP_Data_Interchange_Format), but it looks like your data is a little bit mangled, as your `dn` ends with a comma and your `cn:` and `mail:` are both on the same line.

I'm going to change it to this for the sake of this answer:

```
$data = @"
dn: cn=username,ou=organisationname,ou=org-ca,ou=go-pki,o=finance of organisation,st=on,c=ca
cn:username
mail:username@org.ca
uid: username
goEmpid:2273773

dn: cn=username1,ou=organisationname,ou=org-ca,ou=go-pki,o=finance of organisation,st=on,c=ca
cn:username1
mail:username1@org.ca
uid: username1

dn: cn=username2,ou=organisationname,ou=org-ca,ou=go-pki,o=finance of organisation,st=on,c=ca
cn:username2
mail:username2@org.ca
uid: username2

dn: cn=username3,ou=organisationname,ou=org-ca,ou=go-pki,o=finance of organisation,st=on,c=ca
cn:username3
mail:username3@org.ca
uid: username3
goEmpid:2273776
"@
```

The next thing is probably to parse the data into records that we can work with easier. This is by no means a complete LDIF parser, but it works for your sample data so hopefully i's good enough to work with the rest of it as well...

```
function ConvertFrom-Ldif
{
    param(
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
       [string] $ldif
    )
    $records = @( $ldif -split "`n`n" );
    $records | foreach-object {
        $fields = $_ -split "`n"
        $record = $fields | foreach-object `
            -begin {
                $properties = [ordered] @{}
            } `
            -process {
                $split = ($_ -split ":").Trim()
                $properties[$split[0]] = $split[1]
            } `
            -end {
                return [pscustomobject] $properties
            }
        $record
    }
}
```

This gives:

```
$records = ConvertFrom-Ldif $data
$records | format-list *

dn      : cn=username,ou=organisationname,ou=org-ca,ou=go-pki,o=finance of organisation,st=on,c=ca,cn
mail    : username@org.ca
uid     : username
goEmpid : 2273773

dn   : cn=username1,ou=organisationname,ou=org-ca,ou=go-pki,o=finance of organisation,st=on,c=ca,cn
mail : username1@org.ca
uid  : username1

dn   : cn=username2,ou=organisationname,ou=org-ca,ou=go-pki,o=finance of organisation,st=on,c=ca,cn
mail : username2@org.ca
uid  : username2

dn      : cn=username3,ou=organisationname,ou=org-ca,ou=go-pki,o=finance of organisation,st=on,c=ca,cn
mail    : username3@org.ca
uid     : username3
goEmpid : 2273776
```

And now we can filter to get just the records that have a `goEmpId` property:

```
$filtered = $records | where-object { @($_.psobject.Properties.Name) -contains "goEmpid" }
$filtered | format-list *

dn      : cn=username,ou=organisationname,ou=org-ca,ou=go-pki,o=finance of organisation,st=on,c=ca,cn
mail    : username@org.ca
uid     : username
goEmpid : 2273773

dn      : cn=username3,ou=organisationname,ou=org-ca,ou=go-pki,o=finance of organisation,st=on,c=ca,cn
mail    : username3@org.ca
uid     : username3
goEmpid : 2273776
```

And then finally we can convert the filtered records back to an ldif text string:

```
function ConvertTo-Ldif
{
    param(
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
       [object[]] $objects
    )
    $records = @( $objects | foreach-object {
        $fields = $_.psobject.Properties | foreach-object {
            "$($_.Name): $($_.Value)"
        }
        return @($fields) -join "`n"
    })
    @($records) -join "`n`n"
}
```

to give:

```
$ldif     = ConvertTo-Ldif $filtered
$ldif

dn: cn=username,ou=organisationname,ou=org-ca,ou=go-pki,o=finance of organisation,st=on,c=ca
cn: username
mail: username@org.ca
uid: username
goEmpid: 2273773

dn: cn=username3,ou=organisationname,ou=org-ca,ou=go-pki,o=finance of organisation,st=on,c=ca
cn: username3
mail: username3@org.ca
uid: username3
goEmpid: 2273776
```